# Test for linear dependence of 3 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have these 3 matrices and I have to check if they're linearly independent or dependent without the notion of rank or determinant.

$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix} 
B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix} 
C=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix} 
D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
$

What should I start with?

Comment: There are three kind of mathematicians: those who can count and those who cannot :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can :) but I just know the definition of linear dependence and I can't understand how to translate it with real values

Comment: All right, if I do that I get 0 so that tells me that they're linearly dependent. What about the scalars that multiply each matrix?

Comment: See below. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_1=A,A_2=B, A_3=C,A_4=D$ be the matrices. Note that $A_1+A_3 = A_2 + A_4$.

In particular, there are numbers $\alpha_k$, not all zero, such that
$\sum_k \alpha_k A_k = 0$.

Comment: That's easier than I thought, but I guess it's just in this case...

Comment: Yes, in general it requires more work.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help! @copper.hat

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: You mean $A+C=B+D$ in this example... 

Note: If one has to find out a single non-trivial example (except for the case $\alpha_k=0 \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$) for disproving linear independence, this could turn out to be quite time consuming.

A more systematic way would be to write down the $N^2$ elements of the matrices as columns of a $N^2\times N^2$ matrix. If the determinant is zero, we would know that the columns are not all linearly independent.

Comment: In this case - [https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cinline%20det%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D1%5C%5C1%5C%5C0%5C%5C0%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D0%5C%5C1%5C%5C0%5C%5C1%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D0%5C%5C0%5C%5C1%5C%5C1%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D1%5C%5C0%5C%5C1%5C%5C0%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%3D0]

Comment: @DebanjanBasu: The $A-D$ labels were added after I added my answer. Another way, since we can treat this as a Hilbert space, would be to use Gram Schmidt; if one of the resulting vectors is zero, you know it lies in the span of the previous.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Show the linear (in)dependence of the vectors
$$(1,1,0,0), (0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,1), (1,0,1,0).$$

Comment: Now I have to choose 4 different scalars and each one should multiply a single matrix right?

Comment: You have to find 4 scalars (not all zero), multiply them with these vectors, and this should be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Label those four matrices as $A$,$B$,$C$,and $D$.

$A-B+C=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}+C=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=D$

Therefore those four matrices are linearly dependent.